# comparing rank of a number from a reverse sorted array

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, vector, stl

i have an array like this `array={100,50,40,20,10}`, currently rank of 100 is 1, `rank of 50 is 2 and so on.` now i am comparing rank of point **25**, then `new array leader board will be {100,50,40,25,20,10}` and `25` has rank 4.
similarly, if point `120` was to be compared to the original array `{100,50,40,20,10}`, new array leaderboard will be `{120,100,50,40,20,10}` rank of **120** is 1 now. the original question is [this.](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem)
since the array is sorted and if too large and have to call such query a number of times I want to do it recursively but each time I get stuck. my current code to do such operation is;

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int find_rank_pos(vector<int>&array,int val){
    int mid=array.size()/2;
    if(array[mid]<=val){
        int pos=1;
        while(array[pos-1]>val && pos<=mid){
            pos++;
    }
    return pos;
    }
    else{
    int pos=mid+2;
    while(array[pos-1]>val && pos<=array.size()){
        pos++;
    }
    return pos;
    }
}
int main(){
    vector<int>ranked={100,100,50,40,40,20,10};
    vector<int>::iterator ip;
    ip =unique(ranked.begin(), ranked.end());
    ranked.resize(std::distance(ranked.begin(), ip));
    vector<int>player={5,25,50,120};
    for(auto x:player){
        cout<<find_rank_pos(ranked,x)<<endl;
    }
}
```

please help me to optimise my algorithm. kindly looking for the help.

Comment: Using a balanced BST should be a straightforward approach

Comment: `find_rank_pos` can be implemented as a one-liner: `return std::lower_bound(array.begin(), array.end(), val, std::greater<int>{}) - array.begin() + 1;`

Comment: @AbhinavMathur if you can add BST Approach as an answer it will be of huge help to me, Thank you!

Comment: In `find_rank_pos`, you do the median check just once and then you search the left or right part iteratively. Instead of doing the latter part, repeat the median check for the part that you chose above and repeat this. This is known as binary search. Look it up.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError sir, that is where I got stuck due to the presence of a while loop, I thought to do the same but stuck with it, will be thankful if you can suggest a way to do it